# IP address not reachable

Tags: java, ip, ipv4, inetaddress

I am trying to know if an IP address is reachable using the code below. But every time I am getting "Not Reachable" even though the machine is running. I have tried using several alive IPs but I'm always getting "Not Reachable". Please help.

```
public class CheckIP {
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    String ip = "78.46.84.171";

    if(InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(100)){
        System.out.println("Reachable.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Not Reachable.");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping the machine from the command line? E.g. `ping 78.46.84.171`?

According to the [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable-int-):

> Test whether that address is reachable. Best effort is made by the
>   implementation to try to reach the host, but firewalls and server
>   configuration may block requests resulting in a unreachable status
>   while some specific ports may be accessible. A typical implementation
>   will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the privilege can be obtained,
>   otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection on port 7 (Echo)
>   of the destination host.
>
> The timeout value, in milliseconds, indicates the maximum amount of
>   time the try should take. If the operation times out before getting an
>   answer, the host is deemed unreachable. A negative value will result
>   in an IllegalArgumentException being thrown.

To summarize the possbile errors:

- Is a firewall blocking ICMP requests? (see above ping command)
- Maybe your timeout with `100 ms` is to short (try to increase to, e.g. 1000)
- Are you using Linux / Mac? Maybe you lack the privilege to do pings, so the `isReachable(int)` implementation tries a TCP-Connect but fails. (try a windows machine or execute your program as root or via `sudo`)

Comment: Note the 'if privilege can be obtained'. Typically it can't. And the Windows imp,emendation doesn't use ICMP. So the typical implementation really uses TCP port 7.